# Is there a way to search for a matching string with multiple variants in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains the colum "CompanyName".
I want to get all rows that mach with a specific string.

```
+----+----------------------+-------------------+---------+---------+
| Id | CompanyName          | Street            | City    | Country |
+----+----------------------+-------------------+---------+---------+
| 1  | Microsoft Corporation| One Microsoft Way | Redmond | USA     |
+----+----------------------+-------------------+---------+---------+
```

Is there a way to search for "Microsoft Corporation" or "Corporation Microsoft" and get back row with id '1'?

My problem is, if my customer is searching for "Corporation Microsoft" in my WebApplication he will not get row 1 return with the following code for lookup:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CompanyName LIKE %searchPattern%
```

The WebApp is coded in C#.

SQL-Version: SQL Server 2017 (14.0)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would you please share your query as-is?  Then we can show you what to add to meet your goal.

Comment: Yeah, it is quite easy. You can check the [SQL where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).Note: Adding tsql links because of SQL Server tags in the question.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please read this before posting https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to return the same row when looking against different variations of a the columns's content. This isn't so easy and you will most likely have to apply string comparison algorithms which are not in SQL Server, like Smith Waterman, Levenshtein distance or other fuzzy mechanics. You can use a CLR custom function for this, or try out `SOUNDEX` but it's very limited.

Comment: You can use `where companyname in ('Microsoft Corporation', 'Corporation Microsoft')`. But is this really what you are looking for? What search keys do you want to use and what combinations do you want to include in or exclude from your results? Would you consider `'The Microsoft Corporation'` a match? Define the rules.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I tried your code and it worked. I get the corresponding data set back for both variants. I think i have to code some algorithm for the sql query in C#. Thank you Thorsten

Comment: @Fourat Sorry not the best first post. I added additional data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need full-text installed in your instance, then you can do :

```sql
SELECT * FROM COMPANY WHERE CONTAINS(CompanyName,'Corporation Microsoft')
```

Follow this guide to setup full-text : https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-filestream-and-sql-server-full-text-search/

Read more about full text search : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017

And CONTAINS function : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sorry, for late response. Thanks. This is exactly what i' am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you:

```
select *
from t
where CompanyName like '%Microsoft%'
```

Comment: I have updated my question.This will not work for me, because i don't know the search pattern from my customer. I have to code some algorithm in c# for the sql query. Thank you.